# How store decimal/doubles in OpenXML Excel cells when globalisation sets comma as decimal separator

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, openxml, export-to-excel

I'm trying to create an Excel worksheet in C# in OpenXML, but end up with Excel having to "repair" the Workbook because of doubles have been stored with commas as decimal separators in the Excel /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml file.

My Excel and Windows globalisation is Swedish, which sets decimal separators to comma whenever a double is converted to a string.

When I do a

```
double d = 355d/113d;
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(d);
cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
```

what is actually stored in the Excel's /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml is

```
<x:c s="4" t="n">
    <x:v>3,14159292035398</x:v>
</x:c>
```

with comma as decimal separator. And that makes my Swedish Excel force a "repair" and converts the cells to text/string instead of the numeric values. I can manually convert to numeric values with minimal effort inside Excel, but that is not acceptable in this application.

Looking at the /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml AFTER "repair" and manually converting the strings to decimal values, they are stored as

```
 <v>3.1415929203539825</v>
```

WITH a dot as decimal separator.
The obvious solution - so I thought - was to force store my decimal value with a dot instead with something like

```
double d = 355d/113d;
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(d.ToString().Replace(",", ".").Replace(" ", ""));
cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
```

and a few (!) more varieties to make sure that cell.CellValue contains a dot instead of a comma. But then my Swedish Excel goes bananas and refuses to interpret the value as a decimal, and makes it an int instead.

So I'm stuck. Does anyone have a clue on how to store a decimal value in the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell that Excel will interpret correctly, without repairs, in a system that uses comma as decimal separator by default?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this but what about something like:

```
var nfi = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat;
...
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(d.ToString(nfi));
```